# How to find the minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Let

$$T : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \qquad T(A) = A^{t}$$

I want to find its minimal polynomial, but in order to do that I need to find the matrix basis $[T]_{\tilde{e}}$ lets say $\tilde{e}$ is the basis of a matrix. Which means that its consider by the vectors after we bring the matrix to its  row-echelon form.

I am quite confused could someone help me understand how to find $[T]_{\tilde{e}}$ and the minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pick any basis. Since $(A^t)^t$ is identically equal to $A$, $p(x)=x^2-1$ annihilates $T$. If you can prove that no linear polynomial annihilates $T$ (note: whether $n$ is greater than $1$ is essential here), then $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Comment: I can understand that $T^{2}(A)=A$ I can't understand how that says $p(x)=x^2 -1$ are you using the cayley hamilton theorem ?

Comment: @PetrosK $T^2(A)-A=0$ means that $(T^2-\operatorname{id})(A)=0$. Hence $x^2-1$ annihilates $T$.

Comment: ooh ok now I see, thank you very much.